# Can we download DSE i.e datastax Enterprise graphDB and store in a file

Tags: caching, datastax, graph-databases, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have a requirement where I want to download DSE i.e datastax Enterprise graphDB from server and store it on client in client's cache. This will be a small graph. Later, on client I want to be able to read this graph from local file/cache and use it to serve the requests (do faster lookups/traversal). Is this possible? how?

Answer (score 0):

DSE Graph is designed as a distributed, highly available, server based Graph database.  It is not meant to be an embedded, client side graph database.

Comment: Cant I do any client side caching for it?